# Comparing user Input to data in comma-delimited file and return data from file if matches input

Tags: c#

I have a CSV file with a single column containing people names.
I need to take both the user input and the data in the file, strip all `non-alphabetical characters`, then convert to lower case before comparing with the two.

The file looks like this:

[image]

For Example:
Lets say the user enters: Obrien and the `csv file` contains O'Brien. To compare the two I need to make both lowercase, remove the apostrophe before comparing.

If the name matches, then I will return the name in the file *(not the user input)*.

**I am unable to compare the data when there is more then one name or row in the file.**

```
public string MatchedName(string input)
{
     string nameMatch = null;
     string[] matchList = null;
     const string matchFile = @"C:\matchedfile.txt";

     using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(matchFile))
     {
            string matchContent = "";
            while ((matchContent = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {    
                   matchList = matchContent.Split(',');
            }
     }

     foreach (string name in matchList)
     {
          nameMatch = name;
     }

     if (String.Equals(RemoveCharTab(input), RemoveCharTab(nameMatch)))
     {
          return nameMatch;
     }
     else
     {
          return input;
     }
}
```

And the following `Regex` to strip unwanted characters.

```
    public string RemoveCharTab(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), @"[^a-zA-Z]", "");
    }
```

Comment: Please post the actual content of the csv file

Comment: according to given code you are just splitting last row of text file. If you want to look into whole file you have to do comparison in `while loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code selects values in last row, not the column with names.
Try the following code:

```
public string MatchedName(string input)
{
    const int nameColumnIndex = 0;
    const string matchFile = @"C:\matchedfile.txt";

    string normalizedInput = RemoveCharTab(input);

    string[] names = File.ReadAllLines(matchFile)
                         .Select(l => l.Split(',')[nameColumnIndex])
                         .Select(s => s.Trim())
                         .ToArray();
    return names.FirstOrDefault(n => string.Equals(RemoveCharTab(n), normalizedInput)) ?? input;
}
```

Comment: Hello, this returns the match with the quotes around the value. Just an FYI: Thanks!!

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Do you mean that you have values like this `"O'Hara"` or even values with comma inside like `"Ramzes,III"`? If latter is the case and you have more than one column in csv file, then you **cannot** just split the row by comma.

Comment: Sorry, that was mine fault. I was using a test file. This is working as expected, thank you so much for your time and effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **I am unable to compare the data when there is more then one name or row in the file.**

Because according to given code you are just splitting last row of text file. If a file contains just one name that will be fine. Otherwise if there are multiple rows then you are just comparing last row only.

You have to split and compare each row in `while loop`. See following code:

```
public string MatchedName(string input)
{
    string nameMatch = null;
    string[] matchList = null;
    const string matchFile = @"C:\matchedfile.txt";

    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(matchFile))
    {
       string matchContent = "";
       while ((matchContent = r.ReadLine()) != null)
       {    
           matchList = matchContent.Split(',');

           foreach(string name in matchList)
           {
                if (String.Equals(RemoveCharTab(input), RemoveCharTab(name)))
                {
                     nameMatch = name;
                     break;
                }
                else
                {
                     continue;
                }
           }

           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameMatch) == false)
              break;
           else
              continue;

       } //end of While
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameMatch) == true)
    {
        return input;
    }
    else
    {
        return nameMatch;
    }

   return string.Empty; //or something as per your requirements
}
```

**NOTE**: if input is comma-separated then you need to split otherwise you can use just string.

Comment: Hassan, I am a little confused here: Shouldn't I be returning a value to the method? The code is a great example but just wondering if you missed that?

Comment: Yes method should return in any case. Can you clarify what should it return when no file is found or input is not matched. Most of the case true and false a boolean is good but let us know what it should return. For the time being I am adding one return statement.